# What are the differences between a WAV file (.wav) and a WAVE audio file (.wave)?

Tags: python, wav, pyaudio, wave, python-playsound

I am trying to use the PyAudio library to record guitar audio through my USB audio interface in a python project. When I use audio applications such as Audacity to save the audio I get a WAV (.wav) file which can be played using apps such as Groove music, windows media player etc. and I am able to manipulate the files as I need.

However, now I need to implement recording into the project and when I use PyAudio to record guitar input, it saves the audio as a WAVE Audio File (.wave) file which cannot be manipulated in the program and cannot be played using the playsound library. When I try to play it from my file manager it will only play using Itunes while Groove music and windows media player don't support it.

Anywhere I check online describes WAVE and WAV files as the same thing so I am unsure why I am having this issue. My code is as shown below. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from playsound import playsound


CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "live_guitar_input.wave"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("NOW RECORDING")

frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("Finished Recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
playsound(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Try rename the file .wav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the O.P. "wave" and "wav" are the same thing. But the file manager application does not recognize wave extension. The solution is just to rename the "file.wave" to "file.wav".

Comment: Thank you for the help!